# How to make multiple properties valid to one file by set_source_files_properties in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I am writing a CMakeLists.txt for a project, and encounter a problem with set_source_files_properties.

The original working expression is:

```
set_source_files_properties (a.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS
    DIR1="/home/xxx/b.i")
```

Then I try to add more COMPILE_DEFINITIONSs, but get failure.

try 1:

```
set_source_files_properties (a.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS
    DIR1="/home/xxx/b.i" DIR2="/home/xxx/c.i" DIR3="/home/xxx/d.i")
```

try 2:

```
set_source_files_properties (a.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS
    DIR1="/home/xxx/b.i")
set_source_files_properties (a.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS
    DIR2="/home/xxx/c.i")
set_source_files_properties (a.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS
    DIR3="/home/xxx/d.i")
```

result:
only last define DIR3 can be recognized in a.cpp when compiling by make, first two are reported undefined in make phase.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: the problem has been resolved by: add_definitions (-DDIR1="a")
add_definitions (-DDIR2="b")
add_definitions (-DDIR3="c")

Answer (score 16):

The `set_*_properties()` functions are shorthands for basic usage. For "advanced" cases, it's better to use the full power of `set_property()`:

```
set_property(
  SOURCE a.cpp
  APPEND
  PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS
  DIR1="/home/xxx/b.i" DIR2="/home/xxx/c.i" DIR3="/home/xxx/d.i"
)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But I got error in cmake phase: CMake Error at source/lte/turbo/CMakeLists.txt:31 (set_property):
  set_property given invalid scope TurboOcl.  Valid scopes are GLOBAL,
  DIRECTORY, TARGET, SOURCE, TEST, CACHE.

Comment: You must have missed the `SOURCE` keyword.

Comment: Great answer! Not clear why `set_source_files_properties` is not delivering what it promises...

Comment: @Antonio Because it doesn't have support for the `APPEND` keyword or equivalent functionality.

Comment: set_source_files_properties takes a list of values separated by ``;`` while set_property will create a list from the arguments.

Comment: @Fred `set_source_files_properties` does *not* take a list of values. It takes a list of alternating property - value pairs: `set_*_properties(.. PROPERTIES prop1 val1 prop2 val2 ...)`. Of course, as always, you can pass a list as a single value if you quote it.

Comment: @Angew I wasn't clear and you stated what I meant.  The ``PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`` takes a list. So if you set the property to ``A;B;C`` then on the command line you will get ``-DA``, ``-DB``, ``-DC``.

Comment: My main reason to prefer `set_property`  over `set_*_properties` is that properties can be appended so there is no risk of losing something that was already set elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I manage to provide several `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` using `set_source_files_properties` with the following command:

```
set_source_files_properties (a.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS
    "DIR1=\"/home/xxx/b.i\";DIR2=\"/home/xxx/c.i\";DIR3=\"/home/xxx/d.i\")"
```

source: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/prop_sf/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code worked for me:

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES("source1.cpp" "source2.cpp" PROPERTIES
COMPILE_FLAGS "-IDir1  
-IDir2 ")

Answer (score 0):

The CMake manual for [COMPILE_DEFINITIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) describes how to achieve this,  and in your case, it would be:

```
set_source_files_properties(a.cpp
  PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "DIR1=/home/xxx/b.i;DIR2=/home/xxx/c.i")
```

The resulting compile command would be:

```
$ /usr/bin/g++ -DDIR1=/home/xxx/b.i -DDIR2=/home/xxx/c.i
```

This also works with values that have spaces, since CMake escapes the value correctly. Consider the following example;

```
set_source_files_properties(a.cpp
  PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "DIR1=/home/x x/b.i;DIR2=/home/xxx/c.i")
```

The resulting compile command would be:

```
$ /usr/bin/g++ -DDIR1="/home/xx x/b.i" -DDIR2=/home/xxx/c.i
```

Answer (score -4):

the problem has been resolved by:

```
add_definitions (-DDIR1="/home/xxx/b.i") 
add_definitions (-DDIR2="/home/xxx/C.i") 
add_definitions (-DDIR3="/home/xxx/D.i")
```

Comment: It's good that it works for you, but for the sake of future readers, I'll add that this doesn't do quite what you asked for. It adds the define to *all* files in the project, not just to `a.cpp`.